# Python Boto3 Custom Metric get_metric_statistics

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I can't seem to get any data on this script for Memory but for CPUUtilization it does work flawlessly. Yes there is data on the mem_use_percent metrics in the cloudwatch metrics it's just the script returns [] did I miss anything?

**CloudWatch Dashboard**

**Custom Namespaces:** CWAgent

**Metric Name:** mem_used_percent

```
import boto3
import datetime

server01="i-0605c842eef1ac2ee"

STime=datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
ETime=datetime.datetime.utcnow()

server01_client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
server01_res = server01_client.get_metric_statistics(
    MetricName='mem_used_percent',
    StartTime=STime,  # These should be datetime objects
    EndTime=ETime,  # These should be datetime objects
    Period=300,
    Namespace='Custom/CWAgent',
    Statistics=['Maximum'],
    Dimensions=[{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': server01}]
    )

print("server01 ",server01_res['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum'])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract_test.py", line 22, in <module>
    print("server01 ",server01_res['Datapoints'][0]['Maximum'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

if you print only the server01_res function the Datapoints[] is empty

```
{'Label': 'mem_used_percent', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '70ff0af7-37c4-466c-99b2-c1e5fa4e5668', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '70ff0af7-37c4-466c-99b2-c1e5fa4e5668', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '339', 'date': 'Mon, 12 Jul 2021 20:17:59 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Thank You

Comment: You could be using boto3 in different region or account than that in console.

Comment: You can use `list_metrics()` to confirm that the `MetricName`, `NameSpace` and `Dimensions` are correct.

Comment: i can confirm it is working because i was able to pull data if i change it to CPUUtilization AWS/EC2 metrics but for mem_use_percent it doesn't have data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It helped to add **ALL** three dimensions `InstanceId`, `ImageId` and `InstanceType`. If you only use InstanceId then no data points are returned.

```
Dimensions=[
    {
        'Name': 'InstanceId',
        'Value': instance_id
    },
    {
        'Name': 'ImageId',
        'Value': image_id
    },
    {
        'Name': 'InstanceType',
        'Value': instance_type
    },

],
```